# Magento 2: specific store selector for custom module in admin form

Tags: magento2

Hello I how add this store selector (first in photo) to my ui_component.
Maybe someone have xml file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your UI_component file XML

```
<field name="storeviews">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">wybór multistora</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain where to add this code or what it does. While this may be the correct solution it offers no value to the next person who won't know what to do with the "answer" you provided.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this

Comment: Where is this file found? Why/how does this fix the issue? You didn't correct anything, you just added 7 words that have minimal substance or context to answer the question, and your original answer is a snippet of code. Since you are the author of this question, provide documentation to what led you to the answer of your own question and *explain* why this is a solution rather than just exclaiming that this works. [You might want to look at the docs on how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)